# <__main__.Circle object at 0x05DE4250>

Tags: python

Can somebody help, please?

I am trying to make this program work

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.__radius = radius;
        if self.__radius <= 0:
            raise ValueError('must not be less than or equal to 0')
        elif not isinstance(self.__radius, (int, float)):
            raise TypeError('must be an integer value')

def main():
    try:
        c = Circle("n")
    except ValueError as x:
        print("Error: " + str(x))
    else:
        print(c)

main()
```

The result should be

```
Error: Radius must be an integer value
```

but, instead, I am getting:

```
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

if I change the value of

```
c = Circle("n")
```

to

```
c = Circle(-10)
```

I will get the answer but if I change it to

```
c = Circle(10)
```

I will get this error

```
<__main__.Circle object at 0x05DE4250>
```

Comment: The last line is not an error: it's the output of your `print` function.

Comment: The first *is* an error, trying to compare an `int` and a `str`. The second isn't an error, that's the `str` representation of the class

Comment: You didn't tell Python how to print your `Circle` object, so it prints some generic form of it; that's what you're seeing.

Comment: Your exception checks for only `ValueError` which in your case is not, your exception is `TypeError` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`

You need to change the order of your checks, so that it first checks if the type is correct before doing comparison.

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.__radius = radius
        if not isinstance(self.__radius, (int, float)):
            raise TypeError('must be an integer value')
        if self.__radius <= 0:
            raise ValueError('must not be less than or equal to 0')
```

Now, as to this:

> `<__main__.Circle object at 0x05DE4250>`

This is just the default representation of your object, you can customize this by overriding the `__repr__` method in your class:

```
def __repr__(self):
   return 'Circle of radius: {}'.self(radius)
```

Comment: Consequently (in this example), the `TypeError` should also be expected as possible exception in `main`.